# Materialize css carousel not working with angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, materialize

I am trying include materialize css carousel in angular 2 code.

```
   <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"></a>
```

& javascript is `$('.carousel').carousel();` 
in type script file. But due to href in `<a>` tag (HashLocationStrategy ) it is not working.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about how to ask good questions. Please add some code that demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish and shows what you have tried. Do you get any error in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Carousel in materializecss use a set of divs with classes and jquery to fire the plugin.
In your code you're firing carousel in class ".carousel" but you don't have the properly div with "carousel" class.
Try this code below:

```html
<div class="carousel">
   <a class="carousel-item" href="#foo!"><img src=".../foo.jpg"></a>
   <a class="carousel-item" href="#bar!"><img src=".../bar.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

```js
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() { 
      $('.carousel').carousel();
   });
</script>
```